# Can I play GTA 5 on rdp?

Tags: remote-desktop, gaming

I have a PC which can't run GTA 5 at all, so I am wondering If I can play it on RDP? I tried RDP before to upload large files, but I observe that video quality is low or something I don't really understand, So, Can I use some paid RDP to play GTA 5 on it?

Comment: Can you?  yes.  Will it look good?  that depends entirely on your machines and home network

Comment: Can you play it? Sure, if the host machine is capable of running the game and hosting RDP simultaneously... WIll you be able to play it as if you were sitting in front of the host machine, or even semi-reasonably? Highly unlikely. Due to how RDP works, several aspects are scaled back or disabled to optimize bandwidth usage and processing power needed, including video quality, color depth, and sound quality. The experience of gaming through RDP would likely be poor to miserable at best.

Comment: Get a server, fill it full of expensive video cards, setup [RemoteFX](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ff817578(v=ws.10).aspx), configure GPU virtualization, RDP in and try it out.

Comment: Duplicate: [Can I run games smoothly on a server via RDP?](http://superuser.com/questions/926801/can-i-run-games-smoothly-on-a-server-via-rdp)

Answer (score 4):

While theoretically possible, the hardware bottleneck will now be replaced by a new bottleneck: Networking. The reduced video quality that you've seen is purposefully there to reduce need for bandwidth and lower latency, and trying to play a game like this will not really be playable.

I tested this with Toribash quite some time ago, just to see if it was possible. And Toribash is a lot less demanding than GTA 5.

Comment: Even on dedicated gigabit links with the latest version of RDP, performance is marginal for even watching videos in mid-sized windows, nevermind full screen games.